ASP.NET Core 8 Share identity between projects
I'm developing a multi-tenant environment where all tenants share a single database. This system has users and a user can be in one or more tenants.
The system consists of 2 projects, one for the tenants that, based on the URL, accesses the data of one or another tenant. The other project is common, and does not select any tenant,  it is only a user panel where users can access to modify their data.
Both projects have a login. If they login the tenants' project, they have to be connected also in the user panel project but not the other way around.
The idea is that a user who is logged in the tenants' project can, through a link, open the user panel project already logged. However, if they have logged in to the users' panel, they will not be logged in the tenants' project, since a user may not belong to a tenant.
Ijn summary, I'd want to share authorizations between projects, but if you log in to one project the authorization will be valid for the other project, but not the other way around.
Is this possible?

Possible through SSO, what options have you explored
